# Jest testing Vue Single File Components with Ionic Capacitor plugin imports

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, jestjs, vue-test-utils, capacitor

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/calebbergman/capacitortest.git) of the issue.

I'm building an Ionic app using Vue and Capacitor. I'm setting up unit tests using vue-test-utils + Jest. Jest unit tests are failing trying to import Capacitor plugins into Vue Single File Components.

The Vue app was created using Vue CLI 3 (v3.4.0). CLI options included unit testing using Jest. I'm new to unit testing altogether. I've naively tried [mocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules) the @capacitor/core module prior to importing the Vue component; this didn't help.

***jest.config.js*** (Vue CLI default)

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "json", "vue"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
    ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$":
      "jest-transform-stub",
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
  },
  snapshotSerializers: ["jest-serializer-vue"],
  testMatch: [
    "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  testURL: "http://localhost/",
  watchPlugins: [
    "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
    "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
  ]
};
```

***MyComponent.vue***

```
<template>...</template>
<script>
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core'
const { Filesystem } = Plugins
...
</script>
```

***MyComponent.spec.js***

```
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Component from "@/components/MyComponent.vue";
...
```

I expect the test to run without issue. Instead, I get the following error message when Jest tries to import the component on line 2 of the spec file:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property `Filesystem` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

      35 | <script>
      36 | import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core'
    > 37 | const { Filesystem } = Plugins
```

`Plugins` is undefined on line 36, thusly line 37 complains when it attempts to destructure `Filesystem` from it.

In a browser, however, the `Filesystem` object is as follows:

```
{
  "config": {
     "name": "Filesystem",
     "platforms": ["web"]
  },
  "loaded": false,
  "listeners": {}, 
  "windowListeners":{},
  "DEFAULT_DIRECTORY": "DATA",
  "DB_VERSION": 1,
  "DB_NAME": "Disc",
  "_writeCmds": ["add","put","delete"]
}
```

---

I don't know where the issue lies. I don't know if I should be doing something different with Jest, I don't know if I shouldn't be importing Capacitor plugins directly in Vue SFCs like I've seen in some [examples](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/07/mobile-apps-capacitor-vue-js#example-adding-a-capacitor-plugin), or...‍♂️.

Comment: try updating to capacitor 1.1.0, it was released a few hours ago and included a Jest related fix

Comment: Yep, that...that did it   Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @jcesarmobile's comment on the OP, updating @capacitor/core from version 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 resolved the issue entirely.

[Fix: make capacitor compatible with commonjs](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/1575)

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT***

Although this made the test past, upgrading the @capacitor/core package to v1.1.0 (released just hours ago) resolved the issue, too.

---

Following the Jest docs on [mocking Node modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) - specifically scoped modules - I created a `__mocks__` folder under root, created a directory underneath it named `@capacitor` and created a file underneath *that* called `core.js`. So I ended up with a structure like:

```
.
├─__mocks__
│ └─ @capacitor
│    └─ core.js
```

Inside of `core.js` I export the pieces that are imported by the Vue components I'm testing (currently only `Plugins` and `Plugins.Filesystem`):

```
// core.js
module.exports = {
  Plugins: {
    Filesystem: {}
  }
}
```

With those in place the Jest test passes with flying green colors.